# How can I search an item of a Set in another Set

Tags: java, set

Hi I have two Sets which are `Set<Price>` and `Set<Balance>` and a class

```
public class Price{
    private String symbol;
    private String price;
}

public class Balance{
    private String asset;
    private String amount;
}

public class Response{
    private String symbol;
    private double amount;
    private double value
}

Set<Price> prices = new HashSet<Price>();
Set<Balance> balances = new HashSet<Balance>();
```

I added these records to the Sets:

```
[
     Price[symbol=NEO,price=0.031],
     Price[symbol=BTC,price=0.010],
     Price[symbol=ETH,price=0.075],
     Price[symbol=ABC,price=0.045],
     Price[symbol=XYZ,price=0.019],
     //..Thousands records


]

[
     Asset[asset=ETH,amount=0.23],
     Asset[asset=XYZ,amount=0.23],
     //.. Very small relative to prices
]
```

I want to create `Set<Response>` with respect to `Set<Asset>`. In another word, I want to get prices of `Asset`'s I have in `Set<Asset>` from `Set<Price>` and create `Set<Response>` like below

```
[
    Response[symbol=ETH, amount=0.23, value=0.23*0.075],
    Response[symbol=XYZ, amount=1.68, value=1.68*0.019],
]
```

I tried to simplify my question. So I am not sure if should use `List` or `Set` in order keep performance and use streams

Comment: Isn't it better to store Price as HashMap since you cannot have 2 ETH prices? that way you can easily lookup the price for that symbol and use it

Comment: Okey I'll make that change but I actually confuse in how can I that with streams? Or should I use for loops?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<String,Double> price = new HashMap<>()` to store the prices per symbol.
Then building the responses is easy - either with loop or with streams.

Streams:

```
Set<Balance> balances = new HashSet<>();
...
Set<Response> responses = balances.stream()
  .map(b -> new Response(b.getAsset(), 
                         b.getAmmount(), 
                         b.getValue() * prices.get(b.getAsset()))
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Loop:

```
Set<Balance> balances = new HashSet<>();
Set<Response> responses = new HashSet<>();
for(Balance b : balances) {
  responses.add(new new Response(b.getAsset(),
                                 b.getAmmount(),
                                 b.getValue() * prices.get(b.getAsset()));
}
```